# Importing from subfolder in Java

Tags: java

I'm new in Java. So, can someone explain why I can't import java files in the subfolder?

```
src
└── ASCIIGame
        ├── Board.java
        ├── game
        │   ├── Chess.java
        │   └── TicTacToe.java
        ├── Main.java
        └── Menu.java
```

This is the code for import and package

Main.java and Board.java and Menu.java

```
package src.ASCIIGame;

import src.ASCIIGame.game.*;
import src.ASCIIGame.*;
```

game/Chess.java and game/TicTacToe.java

```
package src.ASCIIGame.game;
```

This is the command that I used to compile the code

```
cd src/
javac -sourcepath . ASCIIGame/*.java
```

The error I'm getting into

```
ASCIIGame/Main.java:3: error: package src.ASCIIGame.game does not exist
import src.ASCIIGame.game.*;
```

Comment: Usually you don't refer to the `src` part on imports

Answer (score 1):

Compile with the `-d` flag, with this `javac` will build the appropriate directory hierarchy for you, regardless of source location.

You can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) more information about the `-d` flag:

> **-d directory**
>
> Set the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist; javac will not create it. If a class is
>   part of a package, javac puts the class file in a subdirectory
>   reflecting the package name, creating directories as needed. For
>   example, if you specify -d C:\myclasses and the class is called
>   com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is called
>   C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class. If -d is not specified,
>   javac puts each class files in the same directory as the source file
>   from which it was generated.
>
> Note: The directory specified by -d is not automatically added to your
>   user class path.

So, if you compile like

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath . ASCIIGame/*.java
```

this will create any required directories under `bin` to match the packages declares in your files.